# Why am I getting a "must contain a YAML array" for Symfony Validation yaml file?

Tags: php, symfony, validation, yaml, symfony-validator

I'm using Symfony Validation to accomplish validations on my models (basic PHP classes). When I try to execute the validations, I'm told that my YAML file must contain a YAML array,

`InvalidArgumentException: The file "/Users/me/git/project123/app/Lib//Acme/SiteList/Model/validations.yml" must contain a YAML array.`

My Symfony validations YAML looks like this (using 4 spaces for indentation),

```
Acme\SiteList\Model\SiteListItem:
    properties:
        siteListId:
            - NotBlank: ~

Acme\SiteList\Model\SiteList:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: ~
```

The parse YAML validations file looks like this,

```
array(2) {
  ["Acme\SiteList\Model\SiteListItem"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["properties"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["siteListId"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["NotBlank"]=>
          NULL
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["Acme\SiteList\Model\SiteList"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["properties"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["NotBlank"]=>
          NULL
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm executing validations via this,

```
public function validate(SiteListItem $model)
{
    $validationsPath = APPLIBS . DS . 'Acme/SiteList/Model/validations.yml';

    $parsed =  Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($validationsPath));
    var_dump($parsed);

    $validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()
        ->addYamlMapping($validationsPath)
        ->getValidator();

    /** @var ConstraintViolationList $violations */
    $violations = $validator->validate($model);

    return $violations;
}
```

Comment: I think you have something else going on here.  I copied/pasted your validations.yml file and everything seemed to work fine.  I suspect you may have additional unposted lines in your validations file?  The error message comes from YamlFileLoader::parseFile() I suppose you could start by sticking a debug statement there.

Comment: I think problem is in YamlLoader. Which one of them is in use here? I had a problem recently and I was using one under Routing instead one under Translation component. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a *YAML array*. YAML has *sequences* (list of nodes) and *mappings* (set of key-value pairs). Using the term *array* in this error message is a bad idea by the Symfony authors because an `array` in PHP is what is called a hashtable in most other languages.

That being said, the problem recides in your path:

```
/Users/me/git/project123/app/Lib//Acme/SiteList/Model/validations.yml
                                ^^
```

This double slash likely prevents Symfony from loading the file. The resulting error is certainly not what I would expect for this kind of input.

Comment: You will get a "file does not exist" is the loader cannot find the file.  The double slash is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

a bit old but in case, maybe you omit (or keep commented) the first line of your routes.yml file ?

```
#index:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\HomeController::index
```

doesn't work and give you this error.

```
index:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\HomeController::index
```

is correct.
hope this will help.